# Prove that the nxn all 1 matrix (apart from diagonals which are 0) has -1 as an eigonvector with multiplicity n-1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have no clue how to get started with this.

Induction or something? The general formula for the determinant doesn't appear too helpful.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity $k$, then $A+I$ has the eigenvalue $\lambda + 1$ with multiplicity $k$, and vice versa.

Comment: Please write the full details of the question in the actual question, not the title, it is rather unclear like this.

Answer (score 1):

No need for induction. Let's denote our matrix $A$

1. $A+I$ is a singular matrix with $n$ identical rows, thus is has the eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$ (why?)
2. If matrix $M$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$, then matrix $M-I$ has the eigenvalue $\lambda-1$ (why?)

Try to take it from there, as well as prove these statements.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the first point? Why is the multiplicity n-1? Is it because you can row reduce?

Comment: Yes, that is a good way how to look at it. Depending on your definition of (algebraic/geometric) multiplicity, you might have to do a slightly different proof. But since we can row-reduce, we  for example know that the nulity of the matrix (the dimension of the nullspace) is $n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is $e\cdot e^T-I$, where $e$ is the all-one-vector. From that it should be easy to see what the eigenspaces are.